# Python: run bash commands sequentially

Tags: python, popen

I am running an executable on a bunch of `*.in` files in a directory. My script dumps all commands at once. I want to run `Popen` sequentially after the earlier process has terminated. Here is my script:

```
import glob, os, subprocess
import sys, re, math

exec_path='/Users/me/path/to/exec'
for name in glob.glob("*.in"):
    print name
    output = name+'.out'
    args = [exec_path, '-o', output, name]
    subprocess.Popen(args)
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to [wait](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) for your process to end before moving on with the loop.

Your example could be rewritten like this;

```
import glob
import subprocess

exec_path='/Users/me/path/to/exec'
for name in glob.glob("*.in"):
    print name
    output = name + '.out'
    args = [exec_path, '-o', output, name]
    subprocess.Popen(args).wait()  # <- I've added .wait()
```